# Is it possible to convert timedelta into hours?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

This is my dataframe:

```
issue,time_taken
aa,2 days 20:00:00.95
bb,2 days 19:12:48.276000
```

I just want to convert the `time_taken` column format into hours. I only need the total number of hours.

For example, I have to display output like

```
issue,time_taken,time_taken_hours
aa,2 days 20:00:00.95,68
```

Comment: Looks like you are looking at `datetime.timedelta()` instances. If so, you could use `columnvalue.total_seconds() / 3600` to get an hour value, but how to do this efficiently in Pandas I don't know.

Comment: If the format is always `X days hh:mm:ss`, then just parse out `X*24+hh`

Comment: @cricket_007: that looks exactly like `str(timedelta())` output, no need to parse anything out when you could just use the provided methods and attributes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, I'm not too familiar with the `timedelta` functions

Comment: @cricket_007: turns out the column type is a [subclass of `timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
import numpy as np

df['time_taken_hours'] = df['time_taken'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
print df
  issue             time_taken  time_taken_hours
0    aa 2 days 20:07:49.958000         68.130544
1    bb 2 days 19:12:13.383000         67.203717
```

[Frequency conversion in doc](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion)